# Ways to create a layer of abstraction on top of a reactive database?

Tags: android, realm, rx-java, reactive-programming

I'm fairly new to reactive programming, and I can't seem to wrap my head around how to abstract a reactive database so that I can easily swap them out in the future.

The current target database is Realm, and it's tempting to simply reference them in my DAO classes, which communicates with my repository classes. However, after some thought, I should probably create a layer of abstraction on top of the DAO's so that I don't have a hard dependency on Realm. In this case, it'll be more or less forwarding Realm's inputs and outputs. However, I can see where I might try to make a standard sqlite database reactive.

But before I go down this path, I was wondering if there were better alternatives from people who do have experience in this subject.

Answer (score 0):

> and I can't seem to wrap my head around how to abstract a reactive database so that I can easily swap them out in the future.

You need a common abstraction that represents the latest value of multiple event emissions.

Potential candidates are `io.reactivex.Observable<T>` or `LiveData<T>`.

> The current target database is Realm, and it's tempting to simply reference them in my DAO classes, which communicates with my repository classes.

It's tempting until you realize that a `Realm` instance is thread-local and reference-counted, so if you do that, you won't be able to know when to close the Realm (unless you pass `Realm` to each of your `dao.find*(` methods, or create a `ThreadLocal<Realm>` yourself manually so you can keep track of when to close it.)

> In this case, it'll be more or less forwarding Realm's inputs and outputs. However, I can see where I might try to make a **standard sqlite database reactive**.

While Room and SqlDelight provide support for that, you can look around in [this repo of mine](https://github.com/Zhuinden/simple-stack/blob/master/simple-stack-example-mvvm-fragments/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/simplestackexamplemvvm/core/database/DatabaseManager.java#L225-L269) for how you can create a simple wrapper over SQLite yourself.

> But before I go down this path, I was wondering if there were better alternatives from people who do have experience in this subject.

If you want to make Realm "independent of being Realm" and available for observing without relying on its lazy-evaluation, you can put Realm on a background looper thread (`HandlerThread`) from which you map out the items when you detect change.

These RealmResults on this background looper thread must be kept in a Set to keep strong reference to them in order to retain the ability to listen for changes.

If you stop observing ALL the RealmResults you've opened, then you potentially want to close the Realm automatically.

While I don't really touch the project anymore, you can look at [Realm-Monarchy](https://github.com/Zhuinden/realm-monarchy) (by me) which does exactly what I mentioned above: wrap RealmResults into a `LiveData<List<T>>` so that it can be swapped out with anything else (including for example `Room`). You can dabble in its source code if you like.